# Unexpected cursor movements when trying to move desktop icons

Tags: shortcuts

I have been customizing Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS. When I move a desktop icon/shortcut and click it, it doesn't move. Instead, it keeps moving when I move my mouse and when I click it moves into other unintended places in the desktop. Recently I installed Arc Menu and I don't know if that could have caused the problem.

Comment: When you right click on the desktop, is there an option "customize"? If so, choose the Customize option and then disable the "auto arrange" option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desktop Shortcuts Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412781/desktop-shortcuts-not-working)

Comment: Umm the link you gave me was another question I asked, hasn't been answered yet but thanks and @mchid there is no option and it isn't set to auto arrange because looking at my desktop I have arranged it before and it's saved it's just now for some reason I move an object and it won't place it where I want even when clicked down and when I continue to move my mouse it follows. Thanks anyways for trying.

Comment: There is an option that might be causing this: in settings / Universal access / (under 'Pointing and clicking') Click assist / Hover click. If that's selected it might be doing this. If not I can't help, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 and then to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The bug fixes and new features in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS must have fixed this particular issue.

Comment: Okay Thanks for letting me know :))