# Desktop Shortcuts Not Working

Tags: shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and before I've been able to create Desktop shortcuts fine and now I can't when I click allow launching nothing happens. When I move icons I have to click somewhere else than the desktop to make it not move- basically if I move an icon it still moves when I move my cursor, what's the fix for this, I value any support.

Comment: your question is not very clear due to run-on sentences.  I cannot tell if you can't enable your shortcut, launch it, move it, or all of the above.  Can you please clean this up for posterity?

Answer (score 0):

This is my way I figured out last night.

Is your shortcut for a terminal command by any chance?

If so this is my config:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.1.3
Name= speedtest
GenericName=speedtest.net
Comment=internet speed test
Exec=/bin/sh -c "speedtest --secure;sleep 6"
Icon=/home/user01/Desktop/cmds/speedtest.png
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;
```

I used this terminal command **/bin/sh -c**, before my command **speedtest** because the terminal wasn't opening. This fixed that.
After you execute you have 3 options:

1. **;sleep 6**, which will keep- terminal open for 6 seconds (you can adjust number)
2. **;read** which will close after you press **enter**
3. you can change the terminal settings under:

   ```
    hamburger menu > preferences > (pick) profile > commands > 

    when commands exits: hold the terminal open
   ```

---

if its to execute a program, then type in the path of your file under **Exec=** e.g.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/speedtest
```

---

after this under

```
properties > permissions
```

I, allow to execute, by clicking the tickbox.

---

Then, I right click the file and select "Allow launching", if its there.

---

Then, I copy the .desktop shortcut and paste it in:

```
Home/.local/share/applications
```

this will create a link in your start menu
(if you cant access the .local folder, go to

```
hamburger menu > click; show hidden files
```

---

let me know if that helped or you need any more info.